# Question about Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra": Chapter 7 Exercise H2

Tags: group-theory, permutations

This is a very straightforward question

Here is the problem in Pinter's book:

> Let $A$ be an infinite set, and let $G$ be the *subset of all permutations on $A$* (denoted as $S_A$), where $G$ consists of all the permutations $f$ of $A$ that **move** only a finite number of elements of $A$. Prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_A$.

I can see how to prove that closure is present and the inverses are present...however, I fail to see how the identity permutation $\epsilon$ is present within $G$.

The book provides the following definition for **move**:

*We say that $f$ **moves** $a$ if $f(a)\neq a$*

Obviously, $\epsilon$ doesn't **move** any elements...and therefore isn't a member of the set of *moving* permutations.

Am I missing something here? Does the movement of zero elements somehow "slip in" underneath the phrase *finite number of elements*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of elements moved by the identity is empty.

The empty set has cardinality $0$.

$0$ is a finite number.

Therefore $e\in G$.

Comment: this is what I figured...however, it strikes me as being contradictory to the definition of "move". Specifically, $f$ doesn't move any element...yet somehow that qualifies it to be a permutation that exhibits the property of "moving" a finite number of elements. 

Fair enough.

Comment: @S.Cramer People try to keep simple and short expressions for what looks simplest and most common to them. Here, it may look more natural to you to say "moves a finite number of elements or no elements at all", but that's a long sentence for a kind of property that will occur a lot. On the contrary, the set of maps that move a finite number of elements but do move at least one is something that sounds peculiar and shouldn't be our main focus very often, so we don't mind having to use a long sentence to define it.